# Restrict remote debugging on Android WebView

Tags: android

I am having a webApp that loads in a webView. I don't want remote debugging to be enabled on the webview.

I have read several blogs and unable to find any related to this query. Can someone provide any pointer on this.

Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

allow only for build debug then

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
     WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

or

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
    { WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); }
  }
```

( The default is false.)

source :

[Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews)

[Java Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean))